# Como trago um código HTML armazenado no banco de dados MySQL e printo na tela usando Projeto MVC Express Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js, summernote

Quero printar esse codigo que esta armazenado no banco de dados em meu projeto.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esta aparecendo isso invés do codigo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o DAO que tras a infomação do banco de dados
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o CONTROLLER que faz a requisição
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui esta o EJS que é onde o usuario ve o tópico
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já pesquisei na internet mais nao encontro nada para me ajudar neste problema.

esse codigo é armazenado com editor summernote em MySQL
usei LONGTEXT para armazenar em mysql

Comment: Acho que vale a pena **[edit]** a sua pergunta para remover o código em imagem, em favor do mesmo código em texto, utilizando a devida formatação. [Postar código como imagem não é ideal.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do EJS](https://ejs.co/#docs), a tag que você está utilizando (`<%=`) irá imprimir texto [escapado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-html).

Para imprimir um texto que não seja escapado, você deve utilizar a tag `<%-`. Assim:

```
<%- topico.mensagem %>
```

> Lembre-se que isso pode trazer sérias consequências de segurança. Tenha certeza que `topico.mensagem` é um valor seguro antes de imprimi-lo na tela. Você pode estar abrindo o seu site à vulnerabilidades sérias como *[Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)* se estiver não estiver tratando os dados corretamente.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Não tinha aprendido isso.